# Maxmind Injecting new DatabaseReader as a singletone to avoid re-accessing the file again and again

Tags: .net-core, maxmind

In a .net core web app, I want inject a `new DatabaseReader` as a singleton. Therefore i use the AddSingelton in my Startup-Class.

```
services.AddSingleton(x => new DatabaseReader(pathToFile));
```

Do you think its a good idea to reuse `DatabaseReader`?
Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A single connection is a bad idea - if access to the connection is properly locked, it means that website / application could only serve one user at a time.

This means that you are extremly limited in your application scalability and have no ability to get a lot of users.

There is also a problem when your connection is not locked very well, things can get weird.

For example, one thread might dispose the connection while another thread is trying to execute a command against it.

A better possibility is to use connection pooling by creating a new connection object when you need one. So you can handle many requests at the same time and your limitation should be the database.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you should reuse the `DatabaseReader` across concurrent requests. The reader is thread safe and does not rely on locks for that thread safety.

Comment: This is also what is stated in their documentation on GitHub:
https://github.com/maxmind/GeoIP2-dotnet?tab=readme-ov-file#database-usage
And this is regarding Multi-Threaded usage:
https://github.com/maxmind/GeoIP2-dotnet?tab=readme-ov-file#multi-threaded-use